# Cassandra: cannot restrict 2 columns using clustering key(version 2.1.9)

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have a schema pretty similar to this:-

```
create table x(id int, start_date timestamp, end_date timestamp, 
primary key((id), start_date, end_date)) 
with clustering order by (start_date desc, end_date desc);
```

Now I am stuck with a problem where I have to query between start date and end date. something like this : -

```
select count(*) from x where id=2 and start_date > 'date' and end_date < 'date' ;
```

But it gives me an error similar to the following: -

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "end_date" 
cannot be restricted (preceding column "start_date" is restricted 
by a non-EQ relation)"
```

I am new to cassandra, any and all suggestions are welcomed even if it requires us to do a schema change. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which version of Cassandra you are running, but in 2.2 and later you can do multi-column slice restrictions on clustering columns.  This can get close to what you want.  The syntax in CQL is a little ugly, but basically you have to specify the starting range with all the clustering columns specified, like a compound key.  It's important to think about the rows being sorted first by the first column, then within that sorted by the second column.

So assume we have this data:

```
SELECT * from x;

 id | start_date               | end_date
----+--------------------------+--------------------------
  2 | 2015-09-01 09:16:47+0000 | 2015-11-01 09:16:47+0000
  2 | 2015-08-01 09:16:47+0000 | 2015-10-01 09:16:47+0000
  2 | 2015-07-01 09:16:47+0000 | 2015-09-01 09:16:47+0000
  2 | 2015-06-01 09:16:47+0000 | 2015-10-01 09:16:47+0000
```

Now let's select based on both dates:

```
SELECT * from x where id=2 
    and (start_date,end_date) >= ('2015-07-01 09:16:47+0000','2015-07-01 09:16:47+0000') 
    and (start_date,end_date) <= ('2015-09-01 09:16:47+0000','2015-09-01 09:16:47+0000');

 id | start_date               | end_date
----+--------------------------+--------------------------
  2 | 2015-08-01 09:16:47+0000 | 2015-10-01 09:16:47+0000
  2 | 2015-07-01 09:16:47+0000 | 2015-09-01 09:16:47+0000
```

Now you'll notice that one of those end dates appears to be later than our restriction, but it isn't.  Since things are sorted by start_date first, you'll get all the end dates with a matching start_date since they are in the range of the *compound range*.  To get rid of rows like that you'll probably need to do a little filtering on the client side.

See more information [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause), under "Multi-column slice restrictions".

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion, so here we are basically filtering on the basis of start_date and not consider end_date in this case. can I replace it with start_date> 'date' and start_date < 'date'. Would it work any differently? I am sorry, but I am just a little confused.

Comment: You could do that and then filter the end date on the client side.  It would work pretty much the same, but you might get a few more rows at the start and end of the range that you'd need to discard on the client side.  To understand what's happening you have to think of the rows being sorted within a partition.  When you select a slice of that partition you are specifying a start and end point within the partition, and then get everything in between.

Comment: Probably the closest I can get to a solution, thanks :)